# UNNotification delegate function not being called when clicking on Push Notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Whenerver I clicked on the push notification its not being called the delegate function and gives a warning as:

Warning: UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

I couldn't able to find out the real reason behind that as I done all the research about that.

I'm testing this on swift 4.2 & ios 12.1

Comment: Is the app in the foreground or background when this happens?

Comment: @quant24 its neither work on foreground nor background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ClaverTap SDK that throws a warning while clicking on notification. It fixed after changing its instance method before assigning Notification delegate function.